# Crossed out imported java packages

Tags: java, eclipse, import, deprecated

In my java program, I have imported some java packages in one class.
but in there 1 or 2 packages were crossed out.

Why that happened?
How to solve this cross out to make uncrossed?

Comment: I assume this is in eclipse? Are you sure that those packages are being used?

Comment: Yes, it is in Eclipse, and yes, those packages are being used. I can not remove them. @AndrewStubbs

Comment: There is no bulb beside import statements. @TheLostMind

Comment: @SaifulIslam - you can change you eclipse preferences to handle that.. BTW, just press `Ctrl+Shift+o` to automatically manage imports.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those classes are marked as [`@Deprecated`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Deprecated.html).

This means that the compiler advises not to use them, because they can bring you problems.

> A program element annotated @Deprecated is one that programmers are
>   discouraged from using, typically because it is dangerous, or because
>   a better alternative exists. Compilers warn when a deprecated program
>   element is used or overridden in non-deprecated code.

Check the javadoc(s) of the deprecated classes to check which classes to use instead.

Comment: When I mouse over on those packages, it says "Note: This element neither has attached source nor attached Javadoc and hence no Javadoc could be found."

Answer (score 5):

For the sake of completeness, there is a special case which looks like this in Eclipse:

[image: Static deprecated import]

In the case above there exist three `is()` methods, which all are statically imported. Hoovering the crossed out method name doesn't give any information, and there isn't a warning marker like there is for `@Deprecated` classes. In other words, it can be tricky to understand what it means.

In this case, one of the `is()` methods is `@Deprecated`, causing the behaviour.

This behaviour was discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24908818/what-does-a-crossed-out-static-import-in-eclipse-mean), a question which was closed as a duplicate.