# What does a crossed out static import in Eclipse mean?

Tags: java, eclipse

I was just playing around with [JUnit 4](http://junit.org/) so I whacked in these two static imports:

```
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.*;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
```

Wrote the best unit test in the world and did an `optimise imports` in Eclipse just because I have that set to happen on saving a file.

My screen now looks like this (except of course without the big red arrow - I drew that):

[image]

OK, so it is all fine in that it compiles and runs (and the test even passes) but I have the heeby-jeebies because Eclipse has crossed out the `is` and I do not know why.

So, experts, what does this strikethrough mean?

Nervously hovering over it reveals there are three possible `is` methods - could that be the reason?

Comment: 1) Be curious! Move your mouse over the crossed `is`, see what eclipse tells you! 2) Hover over the crossed `is` and hit `F3` maybe you see something special in the implementation ;)

Comment: Thanks everyone.  In my defense, on investigation the is that I am actually using is not deprecated - the is(Class) overload is, however.  I guess the import will bring in all 3 possible versions of that method so eclipse will cross it out if any of the overloads are deprecated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means the method `is` is deprecated.

Comment: ahh, great, thanks, sheesh, I should've thought of that but is sounds just so new and shiny!